# Is there any methods to do in fastapi like SerializerMethodField in djagno

Tags: python-3.7, fastapi

I have to construct a comment API to show whether the current member has liked it.
In Django I can send users infomation by context in serializer.
I have no idea in FastApi.

```
class Level2CommentListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    favor = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = CommentRecord
        fields = "__all__"
        read_only_fields = ['id', 'user', 'article', 'content', 'root', 'replyId', 'depth']

    def get_favor(self, obj):
        uuid = self.context['user']
        if not uuid:
            return False
        data = CommentFavorRecord.objects.filter(comment=obj, user__uuid=uuid)
        if data:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: You'd do this in your regular code - i.e. in your CommentService or however you fetch your comments; you'd then have a field in your response model that represents whether the current comment is liked by the user given when fetching the comments. It's hard to say exactly _how_ that would look without the code from your actual implementation in FastAPI.